# Query Help required for newbie

Tags: sql

I have created 3 tables.

```
tblRegion{RegionID as Integer, RegionName as varchar(100)},

tblCountries{CountryID as Integer, CountryName as varchar(100), RegionID as varchar(3)},

tblUsrs{UserID as Integer, UserName as varchar(100), PrefRegion as varchar(3), PrefCountries as varchar(100)}
```

Now data in each table:

```
tblRegion
---------
RegionID  RegionName: 
1 Asia --
2 Africa --
3 Europe --
4 America

tblCountries
-------------
CountryID  CountryName RegionID:
1 China 1 --
2 Malaysia 1 --
3 Singapore 1 --
4 Afganistan 3 --
5 UK 3 --
6 Spain 3 --
7 Libiya 2 --
8 Morocco 2 --
9 US 4 --
10 Canada 4 --
11 Mexico 4 

tblUsrs
-------
UsrID UsrName PrefRegion PrefCountries: 
1  Mike 2 -1 --
2 John -1 '1,5,9' --
3 Michael -1, '1' --
4 Tango -1 '8,9'
```

From the above data if User passes region as 2, both userID 1 & 4 to be displayed.

I have written query but seems some thing wrong.

```
Select * 
from tblUsers 
where (PrefRegion = '2') or ('2' in (
        Select RegionID 
        from tblCountries, tblUsers 
        where convert(varchar,tblCountries.CountryID) in (tblUsers.PrefCountries)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the wherclause (after the 'or') subselect makes no sense even if the sub-subselect is correct - finding out if it has a 2 for region id has no impact on tblUsers selection at all.

EDIT: thanks Michal for making it readable :)

Perhaps what you need is this on line 3 of your select:

```
where (PrefRegion = '2') and (PrefRegion in (the rest of the subselect) )
```

Comment: can you give a bit more detail of whats not working? SQL erorr or incorrect results set.

Comment: If you see from the data, PrefRegion is 2 for user 1 and for user 4 PrefRegion =-1 but PrefCountries having a countryID 8 which is again under Region 2.

Comment: i c . you can't use "in" operator like that :) you are comparing 2 strings not a string and an array. does this make sense? And you cant use instring because 2 will match 12.

Comment: May be true, but that problem (2, 12) will not come here as I am comparing only with region to region. Anyway I got the answer.

Comment: Select * 
from tblUsers 
where (PrefRegion = '2') or ('2' in (
        Select RegionID 
        from tblCountries  
        where convert(varchar,tblCountries.CountryID) in (SELECT Data FROM Split(tblUsers.PrefCountries,','))))

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you need to do is join the users table to the other two tables, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM regions 
INNER JOIN users_temp ON regions.rid = users_temp.prefRegionID 
INNER JOIN countries ON users_temp.prefCountryID = countries.cid

WHERE(users_temp.prefRegionID = 2) AND (users_temp.prefCountryID = 2)
```

These tables would be joined like this:

[image]

I have removed the prefix tbl from your design (not necessary) and made the assumption that a user would have only a single preferred region and country.  If not, you would use an association type table to store the many preferred values for each user.